# Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'college' available

Tags: spring, spring-boot

my tested code

package com.annotations.annotations;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("college")
public class College {

```
public void id() {
    System.out.println("33");
}
```

@Configuration
public class Config {

```
@Bean
public College name() {
    return new College();
}
```

}

```
import javax.naming.Context;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
     ApplicationContext mech=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    
     College lokesh=mech.getBean("college",College.class);
     lokesh.id();
     
     
}
```

I am getting error like this

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'college' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:872)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1160)
at com.annotations.annotations.App.main(App.java:15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the bean name

```
@Bean(name = "college")
public College name() {
    return new College();
}
```